# in SSIS how to I make the package property CheckPointFileName a variable?

Tags: ssis

It appears this property needs to be hard coded. I'd like to make it a project level variable that I can set from the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Control Flow of the package, right-click anywhere in the design layout and select `Parameterize...`.  From here choose the `CheckpointfileName` property and assign the parameter to use for this file.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!